# Growing Grass from Color Ramp?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, particles, hair

I have added a plane with a color-ramp as texture and added a particle system (grass) as seen below.

what I need to do is make the grass grow from the green area, not the blue area and not from faces or vertex

Is there a way to do that?

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to bake a copy of the node in a grayscale (where the value correspondes to the density of your grass), and use it in your particles' textures with the option to influence the density.

Comment: It worked :) .....

baked the color into grayscale and used it as a texture with density influence.

thanks a lot.

Comment: where can I share the screen shoot of the final result?!

Comment: perhaps this
https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/sites-to-use-for-uploading-images-and-files
might help, thought there are plenty of other options

Comment: here is the result.
[link](https://imgur.com/ymuH0Wo)

Answer (score -2):

it's not possible your only options for growing are by using; vertex weights, textures, grooming(particle edit) or by simply by object.